# How to design a circuit using inverting op-amp when input-output relation equation is given?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, synthesis

Like this:

$$V_0 = 5V_1 - 3V_2 + \frac{V_3 + V_4}{2} - V_5$$

I know about the transfer function but I am not able to make circuits from these relation and I am not able to find it in any book.

Comment: I am not able to find any tutorial or book regarding this. Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 1):

Take all the positive terms. Sum them as necessary in an inverter. Take that inverted sum, and feed it into another inverting summer, along with the negative terms.

Comment: Op amps have two inputs. One should be able to handle everything.

Comment: Yes they can. However, for a beginner the computations required are likely to be incomprehensible. A pair of inverters allows a nice simple approach.

Answer (score 1):

[This is to extend the WhatRoughBeast's answer.  I need to post a picture, that's why I'm posting this as an answer rather than a comment.]

The approach consisting of summing the negatives, summing the positives, taking a difference can be achieved with a single OpAmp.

[image] ([source](http://www.solidfluid.co.uk/sfsite.php/Firmware/OpAmps/MathsOperators?LinearOp.php))

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be easily accomplished by a [summing amplifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Summing_amplifier) op-amp circuit.